# Unable to run sql file in SSMS with 2 Database Engine connections(1 is a Server connection and the other is a local database engine)

Tags: sql-server

I have set up 2 separate Database Engine connections in SSMS 2017. One connection is to the company server databases and the other is for my local database instance. Now, when I open SQL files with code referring to the Server Instance (#1), it fails to run because it doesn't recognize the tables or the attributes. I have to right click on the Server Name in the Object Explorer and open A New Query page, copy the code from the SQL file and paste it onto the new Query page and then run it.

How do I get the SQL file to run by opening it and clicking on Execute?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to reach a different database instance from your local hosted instance, you will need to create a [linked server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/linked-servers-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017).

Once you have that in place you can mix the database connections from a single sql file by using 4 part naming conventions [Server].[Database].[Schema].[Table].